# Bluetooth audio skipping with wifi active

Tags: ubuntu, audio, bluetooth

I've a bluetooth speaker and got it to work. But audio is terrible, skips lots of times:

```
Aug 28 21:02:25 test pulseaudio[2537]: [bluetooth] module-bluez5-device.c: Skipping 309976 us (= 54676 bytes) in audio stream
Aug 28 21:02:25 test pulseaudio[2537]: [bluetooth] module-bluez5-device.c: Skipping 84982 us (= 14988 bytes) in audio stream
Aug 28 21:02:26 test pulseaudio[2537]: [bluetooth] module-bluez5-device.c: Skipping 208448 us (= 36768 bytes) in audio stream
```

Since the wifi and BT come altogether, thought on turning off the wifi connection for a while: **bingo! with wifi disabled BT audio sounds perfect.**

```
lucas@test:~$ sudo lshw -c Network 
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 01
   serial: d8:5d:e2:cc:38:5d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.2 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:b5500000-b5507fff

lucas@test:~$ sudo lsusb -v | grep Blue
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth    Device
  idProduct          0x216c BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
```

I'm using ...

```
lucas@test:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

lucas@test:~$ uname -a
Linux test 4.10.0-32-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:19:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there any possible way of having both BT+wifi active without getting this choppy audio? Might it be due to channel interference?

thanks!

Comment: which media player you are using ? if vlc. please try a different media player like :- firefox, chrome, parole media player .

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this may be corrected by setting the options on the wifi:
Try editing /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
and add either:
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
or
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0

I have had great results with ubuntu 17.10 and the second options.

You may also try updating the kernel to 4.14.1 (the latest stable).
Make sure you do a backup first...

The script for that is:

## !/bin/bash

cd /tmp
wget [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.1/linux-headers-4.14.1-041401_4.14.1-041401.201711210430_all.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.1/linux-headers-4.14.1-041401_4.14.1-041401.201711210430_all.deb)
wget [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.1/linux-headers-4.14.1-041401-generic_4.14.1-041401.201711210430_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.1/linux-headers-4.14.1-041401-generic_4.14.1-041401.201711210430_amd64.deb)
wget [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.1/linux-image-4.14.1-041401-generic_4.14.1-041401.201711210430_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.1/linux-image-4.14.1-041401-generic_4.14.1-041401.201711210430_amd64.deb)
echo Everything is downloaded. Time to install.
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.14.1-*.deb linux-image-4.14.1-*.deb
echo Type sudo reboot to restart your system with the new kernel.

Comment: Hi! Have a couple of questions: a) I think the `iwlwifi` is the driver for intel cards. And I have a Broadcom+BT card, as shown above. Do you know how to tune the same for broadcom? b) I've read the `bt_coex_active` controls whether to enable the coexistence between BT and WiFi. If you set it to 0, aren't you disabling it?

Comment: When setting this to 0, you are not fully disabling it... As I understand it -- When bt_coex_active is enabled it prevents bluetooth/wireless interference. When it is disabled it will allow increased bluetooth/wireless interference.

Comment: b) When setting this to 0, you are not fully disabling it... As I understand it -- When bt_coex_active is enabled it prevents bluetooth/wireless interference. When it is disabled it will allow increased bluetooth/wireless interference.  And apparently in some buggy implementations, the driver thinks that it is transmitting all the time, thus muting the WiFi completely.  So I would experiment with this setting either 0 or 1.  It controls not the coexistence between BT and WiFi, but rather the amount of interference allowed.  - at least as far as I understand it.

Comment: I might experiment with different versions of the kernel - only because of the audio drop out.  I don't know if that would help or not, but it's not a hard change to make. -- Sorry that I don't know the root cause of these drop outs.

Comment: I found an outstanding discussion of the WiFi - Bluetooth coexistence here: https://superuser.com/questions/924559/wifi-connection-troubles-solved-why-does-my-fix-work

Comment: Ok ... I understand your statement. Thing is I've tried your suggestion (edit the iwlwifi.conf) but nothing changed. My guess is that the iwlwifi.conf makes sense only for intel cards and I have a broadcom one. I wonder if there is any chance of tunning the broadcom configuration to allow a better coexistence between BT and WiFi.

Comment: Sorry that I can't help with the broadcom piece.... I was hoping that my suggestions with iwlwifi - might be similar or trigger a thought for your situation.  Have a good one... and best of luck.